# Why am I not getting a sharp, creased edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

All of the sharp edges are creased, but one side is not sharp like the other for some reason.

This side
[image]

should be like this side
[image]

And if I try to add a crease on the corner, I get this
[image]

Comment: could you please share this part of your object?

Comment: Yes, you should give us the .blend file or the .obj...

Comment: @Tareyes sorry for late response, but i figured out my problem, updated the question with an answer, thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

[image]
So it turns out, mediocre to bad topology doesn't sit well with creases. So I fiddled with the topology a bit and achieved wanted results.

Comment: so what was the problem with your topology?

Comment: @moonboots to be completely honest, i'm not *entirely* sure how creasing works, but i got the idea that topology flow, like with subsurf in general, plays a big part. i just looked at the other side of my mesh and tried to work out what could've gone wrong. the best conclusion i could come to is to have simple, well formed quads. as you can see, i had a pointy one in the picture above and it caused weird distortion to the nearby topology